# Meaning of " for the diversion of the young idea"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Young as she was, I was struck,
> throughout our little tour, with her confidence and courage with the
> way, in empty chambers and dull corridors, on crooked staircases
> that made me pause and even on the summit of an old machicolated
> square tower that made me dizzy, her morning music, her disposition
> to tell me so many more things than she asked, rang out and led me
> on. I have not seen Bly since the day I left it, and I daresay that to
> my older and more informed eyes it would now appear sufficiently
> contracted. But as my little conductress, with her hair of gold and
> her frock of blue, danced before me round corners and pattered
> down passages, I had the view of a castle of romance inhabited by a
> rosy sprite, such a place as would somehow, **for diversion of the
> young idea**, take all color out of storybooks and fairytales"

from "The Turn of the Screw", by Henry James

Context: we are in the POV of recently- arrived governesses to the state of Bly. In this passage she asked her pupil, Flora, to show her the place as a way for them to bond.

What does the bold part mean?

Comment: It''s very peculiar phrasing. I'm guessing what he means by the highlighted element is that the way she guided him round the premises was extremely engaging. His tour was so metaphorically "colourful" that ***by comparison*** all his (previously ***vivid***) memories of storybooks and fairytales came to seem dull and colourless. But I find the entire writing style tiresomely verbose, and I'm far from convinced that ridiculously long and circumlocutory first sentence comes anywhere near "syntactically valid".

Comment: What does she mean by "the young idea"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Henry James is a very important writer and the writing reflects his times.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - if you think the book is tiresome, just wait until you see the TV show!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I had the view of a castle of romance inhabited by a rosy sprite, such a place as would somehow, for diversion of the young idea, take all color out of storybooks and fairytales."
from The Turn of the Screw by Henry James

Often, entire phrases are used adjectivally. Written in another way, this would be:
for the idea of diversion of the young.

Comment: Still not clear to me.

Comment: @Ali diversion-of-the-young idea. Not "young idea". :)

Comment: @Ali My only doubt is whether he means to entertain the young or to divert them from some path. Hard to say.